# Reading child registry key from regedit in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to read a registry key's child key name and assign the child key name to a variable. I am not getting an registry query to do it.

For ex: My current key is like this "ProviderName/SoftwareName/8.0". The last part 8.0 can change as and when I switch versions. I would want to read this version number.

Thanks in advance !!
Prakash

Comment: accept some answers on your previous questions first

Comment: Sorry, If I was not clear on my question, my actual question is I am not able to Query the registry for the child key name

Answer (score 0):

the `REG` command is what you will have to parse the output for.

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office
```

will show you office versions (as well as some common keys)

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=\" %a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office') do echo %a
```

will output the information. you will have to convert the info into a number, then test to see if it is bigger.