# Check if product installed successfully

Tags: batch-file, installation

I am working on product testing automation. I just want to ask is there anyway to check that product has installed successfully by using Batch script?

I am using Win7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the way your product installs. Your check script could check for the existence of files:

```
IF EXIST filename (
    REM Do one thing
) ELSE (
    REM Do another thing
)
```

(from [How to check if a file exists from inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340350/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-inside-a-batch-file))

You could also check for registry keys, for example:

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office
```

will output something like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\MS Project
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook
```

depending on what's installed on your computer.

(from [Reading child registry key from regedit in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933254/reading-child-registry-key-from-regedit-in-batch-file))

There are numbers of options, it's better if you can modify/work with the internals of your the installer to know what to check for.

Answer (score 2):

See if your installer returns an errorlevel.  Errorlevel zero is generally an indicator of success

```
@echo off
setup.exe /switches
if not errorlevel 1 echo installation succeeded.
```